# Post Publish date not display on Umaya Child themes

Tags: post-meta, child-theme, date-time, blog-page

I can't find out the option of published date or modified date on my blog post. I write the this code `<?php echo get_the_date() ?>` but can't display the date. this is my [blog post](https://www.applavia.com/blog/how-to-make-a-playlist-on-iphone/) where I try to display the published or modified date. My website Link: [www.applavia.com](http://www.applavia.com)

Comment: Where do you try to display the date?  Can you share the whole block of code where you're applying the `get_the_date();`?  I'd love to help but can't go through all the HTML of your page with my developer tools looking for where they may be an error or some other setting cancelling this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.